POSIX shell command to parse a version string
What is the posix shell (not bash) command to parse and extract the following components of a string?

Given a version in the format of "15.12"
Extract 15 and 12 into their own variables
The script must only use sh and not bash


Use read and a here document.
$ version=15.12
$ IFS=. read -r major minor <<EOF
> $version
> EOF
$ echo $major
15
$ echo $minor
12


Please show same demonstration, but using variables instead of hardcoded version string!

I had trouble using chepner's answer while using variables. Instead I ended up using the following:
$ version="15.12"
$ major="${version%%.*}"
$ echo "$major"
15


Not sure what your issue was; you can expand the variable in the here document.
